# error: template ... Elem (&)[size] ... cannot be overloaded with ... const Elem (&)[size]

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I came accross an error that doesn't make sense to me.

I tried to write a custom `span` class to be used in cases where the operation requires pointer to data and size. It currently looks like this

```
template< typename ElemType >
class span
{
    ElemType * _begin;
    ElemType * _end;

 public:

    span() : _begin(nullptr), _end(nullptr) {}
    span( ElemType * begin, ElemType * end ) : _begin(begin), _end(end) {}
    span( ElemType * data, size_t size ) : _begin(data), _end(data + size) {}

    ...

    ElemType * begin() const { return _begin; }
    ElemType * end() const { return _end; }
    ElemType * data() const { return _begin; }
    size_t size() const { return _end - _begin; }
    bool empty() const { return _begin == _end; }
};
```

But trying to add these constructors

```
    template< size_t size >
    span( ElemType (& arr)[size] ) : _begin(arr), _end(arr + size) {}

    template< size_t size >
    span( const ElemType (& arr)[size] ) : _begin(arr), _end(arr + size) {}
```

and using them in the following manner

```
void foo( span<const char> s )
{
    ...
}

foo("haha");
```

results in

```
error: 'template<long long unsigned int size> own::span<ElemType>::span(const ElemType (&)[size]) [with long long unsigned int size = size; ElemType = const unsigned char]' cannot be overloaded with 'template<long long unsigned int size> own::span<ElemType>::span(ElemType (&)[size]) [with long long unsigned int size = size; ElemType = const unsigned char]'
```

I don't understand why making a const and non-const version of the same would be a problem, especially when my two previous constructors are

```
    template< typename Container >
    span( Container & cont ) : _begin(cont.data()), _end(cont.data() + cont.size()) {}

    template< typename Container >
    span( const Container & cont ) : _begin(cont.data()), _end(cont.data() + cont.size()) {}
```

and the compiler does not have any problems with it.

Why are the constructors from const and non-const plain C array a problem?
And is there any workaround?

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/zd5qc1ovz. Please post a [mcve] and the complete error message

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] of the failing program to show us, how do you use this class to get these errors?

Comment: As a possible hint about your problem, `ElemType = const unsigned char`... The argument for the first constructor becomes `const unsigned char (&arr)[size]`, and for the second constructor the argument becomes `const const unsigned char (&arr)[size]`. With one `const` discarded from the second constructor it becomes exactly the same as the first.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm sorry, you are right. The problem is not in the class but in the way i used it. I tried to initialize parameter `span<const uint8_t>` with string literal `"haha"`. I will edit the question and write an answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, this is the problem. But it's rather a symptom of another mistake i made. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

So i figured it out. The problem is the function declaration

```
void foo( span<const char> s );
```

instantiates the template with `ElemType = const char`, which makes the declarations

```
span( ElemType (& arr)[size] );
span( const ElemType (& arr)[size] );
```

equal (both have `const char`).